# How to organize material-ui Grid into rows?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-design, material-ui

I'm using **material-ui** to do a form, using the `Grid` system I'd like to do the following:

```
<Grid container>
    <Grid item xs={4} />
    <Grid item xs={4} />
    <Grid item xs={4} />
</Grid>
```

And be able to put the first 2 items, on the first row and the third on a second row, the only way I found to do it is:

```
<Grid container>
    <Grid item xs={4} />
    <Grid item xs={4} />
</Grid>
<Grid container>
    <Grid item xs={4} />
</Grid>
```

What is the better way to stack **material-ui** `Grid` into rows (like the row class concept in **Bootstrap** grid)?

I also thought about these options:

- filling the first row with empty `Grid` item?
- putting vertical container?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You are close with the second block of code.

I found that you could simply create 2 distinct Grid sections such as:

```
<div>
  <Grid id="top-row" container spacing={24}>
    <Grid item xs={4}>
      <Paper className={classes.paper}>Grid cell 1, 1</Paper>
    </Grid>
    <Grid item xs={4}>
      <Paper className={classes.paper}>Grid cell 2, 1</Paper>
    </Grid>
  </Grid>
  <Grid id="bottom-row" container spacing={24}>
    <Grid item xs={4}>
      <Paper className={classes.paper}>Grid cell 1, 2</Paper>
    </Grid>
    <Grid item xs={4}>
      <Paper className={classes.paper}>Grid cell 2, 2</Paper>
    </Grid>
  </Grid>
</div>
```

You can play with it in my [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/2412n5nwnp)

It might also be work checking out the [official documentation](https://material-ui.com/layout/grid/) for Grid, as it shows a few ways to use it and also links to each exapmle hosted on codesandbox.io so you can play with it yourself.

From the docs, it seems the best way to have multi-layered grid systems is to define the width of the overall grid and then to define the width of each cell, as this will push cells later in the series onto the other rows.

Comment: basically this is still using 2 containers. Worked with Ant Design and Bootstrap before trying Material-ui, it feels so weird

Answer (score 5):

Here's another approach you could take which *does not* require two grid containers. In Material UI you can organise a grid into rows by using the fact that a row has 12 columns and making use of empty grid items (as Material UI [does not support offset grid items](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/11251)) e.g.

```
<Grid container spacing={24}>
    <Grid item xs={4}>
      <Paper className={classes.paper}>Grid cell 1, 1</Paper>
    </Grid>
    <Grid item xs={4}>
      <Paper className={classes.paper}>Grid cell 2, 1</Paper>
    </Grid>
    <Grid item xs={4} />
    {/* 12 Columns used, so next grid items will be the next row  */}
    {/* This works because Material UI uses Flex Box and flex-wrap by default */}
    <Grid item xs={4}>
      <Paper className={classes.paper}>Grid cell 1, 2</Paper>
    </Grid>
    <Grid item xs={8} />
  </Grid>
```

You can see this working [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/7150p?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark).

Indeed this is actually demonstrated on the Material UI websites (though without the offsets) [here](https://material-ui.com/components/grid/#basic-grid).

I admit though that I'd prefer to see semantic Row and Column elements in Material UI (e.g. like in Bootstrap), but this is not how it works.

Comment: From Material UI's [website](https://material-ui.com/components/grid/): "Material Design’s responsive UI is based on a 12-column grid layout."

So the way to make new rows is to consume the whole 12 columns. +1 to having semantic row/column elements.

Comment: @TanWang "So the way to make new rows is to consume the whole 12 columns" - great explanation.

Answer (score 3):

You can do something like this

```
<Grid container spacing={1}>
    <Grid container item xs={12} spacing={3}>
      <Grid item xs={4}>
        <Paper className={classes.paper}>item</Paper>
      </Grid>
    </Grid>
    <Grid container item xs={12} spacing={3}>
      <Grid item xs={4}>
        <Paper className={classes.paper}>item</Paper>
      </Grid>
    </Grid>
    <Grid container item xs={12} spacing={3}>
      <Grid item xs={4}>
        <Paper className={classes.paper}>item</Paper>
      </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Comment: This is the way how it is done in the documentation. They call it [nested grid](https://material-ui.com/components/grid/#nested-grid).

Comment: This also lets you catch onClick for all columns in the row in one place, which is less repetitive than the other solutions mentioned. Think of the use case where clicking anywhere on a row should spring an edit dialog box.

Answer (score 3):

I created new component to solve this problem:

```
export const GridBreak = styled.div`
  width: 100%
`;
```

Then your code would look like this:

```
<Grid container>
    <Grid item xs={4} />
    <Grid item xs={4} />  
    <GridBreak />
    <Grid item xs={4} />
</Grid>
```

Comment: This is amazing.